# how can download webapge as .html/.png after i inputed text in text box below is my code

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

***how can download webapge as .html/.png after i inputed text in text box  below is my code***

```
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="link">Paste Website Link Below</label>
        <input type="link" class="form-control" id="download" placeholder="Enter website link" >
      <br>
    <butt class="btn btn-primary">Download </button>

</form></div>
```

**i know this thing works for downloading webpage or any file but want when we type link their and then download help**

Comment: You can't put attributes in end tags.

Comment: i know <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download> this thing works for downloading webpage or any file but want when we type link their and then download help

Comment: You can use JavaScript to create another `<a>` download link with the specified file, then trigger it using JavaScript.

Comment: if any user type link their and after that click on download then file is going to download this is my main motto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will create an `<a>` element and assign the download link to it, then click it.

```
function download() {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", document.getElementById("download").value);
  link.setAttribute("download", "");
  link.click();
}
```

Your button should look like...

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="download()">Download</button>
```